# android-how to change customSpinner typeface

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-fonts, android-typeface

this is how I make my spinner , I want to change the font . 
I'm using a custom layout that contains a textView.

How can I do that ?

```
ArrayAdapter<String> SpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Spots.this, R.layout.spinner_item,states);
Spin1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

int the spinner_item.xml, you can set android:typeface attribute at the textview element.